# High Sierra how to move menu bar to external monitor

Tags: menu-bar, spaces

[MBP 2014, Mac OS High Sierra]

I managed to crack the lower left corner of my screen last night, the power cable flicked into the space as I was closing the lid.  As a result, I'm missing a couple inches of screen space on the left side.  This, of course, means that I cannot see the "Apple Icon" (not too big a deal) nor the first, usually "File", menu item.

Since I usually have an external screen plugged in, I would like to move the menu bar to the other screen.  However, I don't want to use the Mission Control function to create another `space` (Desktop).

Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have the external screen connected, in system preferences : Display you can move that menu bar to the other screen - I usually get the displays icon in the menu bar as well.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise you could do that!

Comment: Hint: You can't drag and drop the menu bar itself. You have to go to the Arrangement tab and move the white bar on the monitor images. Given how rearranging the dock and stuff on the touch bar works, this was pretty unintuitive...

Comment: Is there a keyboard short-cut?  This is something that I'd like to do frequently (I have different apps running on different monitors).